# rxjava - how to build stream of integers from stream of observables which contain list of integers

Tags: rx-java

Given a object that looks like the following:

```
class Products {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers;

    public Products(ArrayList<Integer> numbers){}
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }
}
```

and lets say I instantiate it like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers1 = new ArrayList();
numbers1.add(23432);
numbers1.add(5555); 
numbers1.add(323423);
Products products1 = new Products(numbers1);
ArrayList<Integer> numbers2 = new ArrayList();
numbers2.add(234222);
numbers2.add(55665); 
numbers2.add(3278663);
Products products2 = new Products(numbers2);
ArrayList<Integer> numbers3 = new ArrayList();
numbers3.add(266622);
numbers3.add(52225); 
numbers3.add(7763);
Products products3 = new Products(numbers3);
```

Using *RxJava*, how would I convert `products1`, `product2` and `product3` to a stream of Integer?

So given a stream like `products1,products2,products3` I need *RxJava* to build me this stream:

```
23432,5555,323423,234222,55665,3278663,266622,52225,7763
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concatMap()` with `Observable.from(Iterable)`

```
Observable.just(products1, product2, product3)
          .concatMap(product -> Observable.from(product.numbers))
          ...
```